# Should I use asynchronous methods within a background thread?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, multithreading, asynchronous

I've been doing a lot of research on this topic but there is a lot to take in and I'm not sure what applies best to my situation.

I'm making .NET apps that run multiple "Tasks" (not Tasks in the .NET sense, just the word I use).  Each Task will need to do a number of operations continuously until cancelled.  Often involving socket connections or HttpWebRequests.

The current setup is as follows; when a Task is started it creates multiple threads, often 100-1000 threads.  These threads all run the same subroutine that contains a loop with the operations relevant to that app.

Since I'm running a large number of HttpWebRequest/Socket connections at the same time I want to balance the load over all CPU cores as best as possible.  At the moment I use the synchronous GetResponse method of HttpWebRequest.  Since this is happening in background threads I don't care about the thread being blocked, as I need the HttpWebResponse to continue that threads operation anyway.  If I use the Await GetResponseAsync method instead, will that allow the OS to balance the load better?

Ultimately I want to know if there is a point to awaiting Asynchronous methods within a background thread, or is it making the code more complex for no reason?  If there is no point, what are the benefits of using asynchronous code over just doing the job in a background thread?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't each thread take 1 MiB of stack space?

Comment: @MattWilko How would that be possible?  Often the many threads each loop a complex operation, say I GET page X then POST Y, GET Z, etc.  If part fails it often starts the loop again.  Using asynchronous methods on one thread, I assume I'd start GET page X asynchronously 1000 times instead, then in the callback move onto the next part (POST page Y), how would I "re-loop" if something fails?

Comment: @MattWilko I believe I understand that part, the issue is I can't just have one loop running as it isn't going to be fast enough for my needs.  Let say I have to use httpwebrequest to GET 5 pages in a row, an that would constitute a "success".  However I need to do this until I have say, 10000 successes.  I can't just have it GETing those 5 pages then looping round and start getting them again, it would take forever.  That's why at the moment I have 1000 threads performing the same loop.  How would I consolidate the work/speed of 1000 threads into 1?

Comment: @Dirk Correct. According to Jeffrey Richter: “CLR via C# - Third Edition” part V Threading, page 693, "...when managed applications create a thread, the CLR forces Windows to reserve and fully commit the stack immediately, so 1 MB of physical storage is fully allocated as each thread is created."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Async/Await is different than threading. 100-1000 threads is a *lot*, especially for just doing I/O.

Async can reduce the number of threads necessary if you use it in background threads. However, from your current description I agree with the other commenters that it doesn't sound like there is *any* need for background threads at all.

Async/Await is designed to follow the same flow as regular code, so if your code uses `try`/`catch` to retry on failure, then your `async` code would use the same `try`/`catch`, etc.

To do serialized work ("in order"), just `await` the returned tasks:

```
await client.GetAsync(..);
await client.PostAsync(..); // doesn't post until the get completes
await client.GetAsync(..); // doesn't get until the post completes
```

To do concurrent work, collect the tasks and then pass them to `Task.WhenAll`:

```
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
for (int i = 0; i != 1000; ++i)
{
  Task task = DoMyOperationAsync();
  tasks.Add(task);
}
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

You may find my [`async` intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) helpful.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a try.  I knew how to use await just wasn't sure how to bundle a bunch of await operations and run them all at the same time.