# How can I use Await Task.Delay without labeling all methods Async?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, multithreading, asynchronous

I'm working on replacing my old code that uses threads to a .NET 4.5 Task based system.

I've replaced threads with Tasks, next I'm working on replacing my Thread.Sleep calls with Await Task.Delay.  The problems I'm having with this is that await can't be called within a Synclock section and also every method that now uses Await Task.Delay instead needs to be labeled Async.

I can probably get around the synclock issue as I only have a few blocks of those and can be replaced with better code.  However, having to label each method Async is causing problems.  It then means I have to label the method that calls that method Async and so on down the chain.  Eventually all my methods are going to be Async.

Is this how it should be done when using a Task based approach or am I doing it wrong?

Edit 1: Posting example code

```vb
  Public Async Function Delay(Milliseconds As Integer, Optional Initial As Boolean = False, Optional Silent As Boolean = False, Optional Modifier As Double = 0.3, _
                        Optional Task As Task = Nothing, Optional ExitOnTaskStop As Boolean = True) As Tasks.Task(Of Boolean)
    Dim OutputBufferKey As String = Nothing

    If Task IsNot Nothing Then
      If Task.StopRequested Then Return True
      OutputBufferKey = Task.OutputBufferKey
    End If

    If Initial Then
      Milliseconds = Rand.Next(0, Milliseconds)
    ElseIf Modifier > 0 Then
      Dim MinValue As Integer = CInt(Milliseconds * (1 - Modifier))
      Dim MaxValue As Integer = CInt(Milliseconds * (1 + Modifier))
      If MinValue < MaxValue Then Milliseconds = Rand.Next(MinValue, MaxValue + 1)
    End If

    If DebugMode AndAlso Not Silent Then
      Dim LengthString As String = Nothing
      Select Case Milliseconds
        Case Is < 60 * 1000 : LengthString = Math.Round(Milliseconds / 1000, 1) & " seconds"
        Case Is < 60 * 60 * 1000 : LengthString = Math.Round(Milliseconds / (60 * 1000), 1) & " minutes"
        Case Else : LengthString = Math.Round(Milliseconds / (60 * 60 * 1000), 1) & " hours"
      End Select
      Output(OutputBufferKey, "Sleeping for " & LengthString)
    End If

    If ExitOnTaskStop AndAlso Task IsNot Nothing Then
      Try
        Await Tasks.Task.Delay(Milliseconds, Task.CancellationToken.Token)
      Catch ex As OperationCanceledException
        Return True
      End Try
    Else
      Await Tasks.Task.Delay(Milliseconds)
    End If

    Return False
  End Function
```

I need the delay for many reasons and that method is called in a number of other methods. To give a couple of examples I have code that uses the OpenPop DLL to check an inbox for a message to arrive, if it's not there on the first check I need to wait before I check again, I have the loop and a sleep if nothing has been found.  Another example is I need to make a HttpWebRequest to check a file, if the contents haven't changed I want to do this again in 30 seconds.

I suppose using timers would be a better idea?  If so, what is the proper use of Task.Delay?

Comment: "I've replaced threads with Tasks, next I'm working on replacing my Thread.Sleep calls with Await Task.Delay." Why?

Comment: Why do you call `Thread.Sleep`? If you're using it in random places all over the code, you're likely doing it wrong. Separate business logic from task scheduling logic. And you don't actually need to replace all calls of `Thread.Sleep`, but it depends on usage.

Comment: @Sam The way I was doing it previously was creating thousands of threads, I was informed using Tasks was the better way of doing it.  As for Thread.Sleep, Task.Delay seems an improvement as I can give it a cancellation token, so I don't have to Thread.Sleep(100), check for cancellation and loop again.  These recent questions of mine might better explain how I've got here.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25764970/should-i-use-asynchronous-methods-within-a-background-thread
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25773587/how-do-i-deal-without-byref-in-an-async-function/25773634

Comment: @Athari I need to do X, wait 30 seconds, then do Y.  I've never liked using Thread.Sleep and I'm trying to improve the code but the wait is necessary.

Comment: @iguanaman You should post some code, otherwise it's hard to understand why you need to make all your methods async.

Comment: "Async all the way up" Yes. That's the one true way.

Comment: @Athari Posted some example code

Comment: @spender Are you being sincere?  I am here looking for help, if I'm doing it the wrong way I'd appreciate advice.

Comment: @iguanaman he is being sincere, `async` is "infectious", once you have once piece of code that uses it most of the rest of your code will need to start using it if you want to get any benefit from it. Your whole call chain must be async "all the way up" to whatever is pumping the messages for the system you are using.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Thanks, well that does seem to be the direction it's pushing me in if I want to use the Task Parallel Library methods.  It's just a lot of code to re-write, so I wanted to be sure it's the right move before changing it all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The methods that you need to await, should be marked async, not everything.  If you have a simple function that adds `Var1 + Var2`, it would be ridiculous to make that async. That being said, you do end up making a lot of thing async because they call something that calls something that needs to be awaited.

Based on the discussion here, you might be better off with timers which leads to your other question, "what is the proper use of Task.Delay"?  I solely use it so I can wait for my UI to finish what it is doing. For example, I make a call to a database and start a UI transformation to maybe gradually show a new part of the screen over the next 1/2 second. I don't want to fill in my results during that 1/2 second because it often creates a jittery screen so I wait until it is done. The easy way to do this is to make the call to the database, and create a delay then use the `WhenAll` to wait for the last one to finish. This is usually my 1/2 second but sometimes the database.

As a side note, you can call synchronous methods using async that will work in the background as well. This is a much easier transition from threading but since you already changed most of your code, you don't want to here that.